# EDGE TO EDGE NAVIGATION ISSUE

Tags: angular, navigation, microsoft-edge

I have an application in that there is a requirement to open some application in edge. ex. There is button onclick on button there will be a link of application so that it will open in edge only. For that i used this code `RedirectToCostAnalytics() {
    window.location.href = 'microsoft-edge:https://google.com/';
  }`

When i run application in chrome & IE it's working, but when I run application in edge and click on button it gives me 'ERROR:NAVIGATION' Message. Is this common issue or i am doing any mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Edge you're using? I've tested on Edge Legacy and Edge Chromium, the url scheme can't open on either Edge browsers, but I didn't see any error.

As a workaround, you can check the browser version before you open the link:

```
window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1  //check for Edge Legacy
```

```
window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") > -1   //check for Edge Chromium
```

Working Code Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="test" onclick="RedirectToCostAnalytics()"/>
    <script>
        function RedirectToCostAnalytics() {
            if ((window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1) || (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") > -1)) {
                window.location.href = 'https://google.com/';
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = 'microsoft-edge:https://google.com/';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```